# Several errors come up attempting to install Octokit.ObjC

Tags: ios, octokit

I am attempting to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc) to manually install the Octokit.ObjC into an iOS app. I end up having to hunt for `Mantle.xcproject` and `ReactiveCocoa.xcodeproj` because they were either not in the `External` folder like stated or hidden deep somewhere.

This is what I had at the end of step 3:

[image: Everything looks ok.]

After I finally had everything in order, I preformed steps 4-6. At step 4, there was a problem, all I could find were the `.framework`s and not the static libraries I needed to link to. I attempted to add the `.framework`s, and performed the next two steps, but when I tried to build, I got several errors that looked like this:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nccaebi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-blvlvtenpfppypfxalvsfrqgyflx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nccaebi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-blvlvtenpfppypfxalvsfrqgyflx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISO8601DateFormatter.framework/ISO8601DateFormatter'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nccaebi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-blvlvtenpfppypfxalvsfrqgyflx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.framework/.framework'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nccaebi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-blvlvtenpfppypfxalvsfrqgyflx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OctoKit.framework/OctoKit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nccaebi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-blvlvtenpfppypfxalvsfrqgyflx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.framework/.framework'
```

I highly suspect that this is because I linked the `.frameworks` instead of the `.a`s, but I had no idea where the `.a`s were. How can I find them?

[image: ???]

If it matters any this is a Swift app not Objective-C, i planned to use a bridging header to use Octokit.

Comment: How did you perform the step 2? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem but I got to work it. The problem was that I did not cloned the repository from GitHub. Instead I simply downloaded the code. In the downloaded code, you might not get all the files you need. So here are the steps to get this thing work:

1. Download the GitHub application for Mac, if you don't have already, & clone the octokit repository. Once successfully cloned, you must have all the files.
2. Install the Homebrew on your Mac, if you have not already, using command below:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```

   This should install the homebrew on your mac. Don't skip this step as it is necessary to install the bootstrap mentioned in the 2nd step of the documentation.
3. After the successful completion of step 2, run this command on terminal:

   ```
   brew install xctool
   ```

   [image]

   This would install xctool.
4. On the command line, go the path of the folder just before the 'script' folder, where you have cloned it, and type below command on terminal:

   ```
   script/bootstrap
   ```

   [image]